How do I get the full sql code for all queries in all MS Access databases of a folder?
I want to run RegEx on the full SQL code of hundreds of MS Access queries that I loop through with VBA over all Access databases that can be found in a folder.
The "SQL" attribute of the query object comes in already as a String, and if you copy the code from the Locals Window to some editor, it has been cut at 255 characters:

Thus:

It seems to work only for shorter SQL code: Getting sql string from a query:
Private Function GetQuerySQL(MyQueryName as String) as String
Dim QD As DAO.QueryDef
 
Set QD = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(MyQueryName)
GetQuerySQL=QD.SQL
 
End Function

How do I get the full SQL code that can be longer than the 255 characters of a String variable, looped through all queries and all databases of a directory? This does not have to be answered in VBA, but it would be first choice.

This post describes how to compare two memo fields using VBA. Perhaps this would work for RegExp ...

This post describes how to use regex within SQL Server but that would involve changing your back end database. Interesting though, good question.

I ran into a beginner's mistake here. If I Debug.Print obj.SQL (the query's SQL String), I get the full SQL code in the "Immediate Window".
Thus, the String variable is not cut at 255 characters, only in the "Locals Window", it is cut in the preview. Since I copied the preview text from the "Locals Window" to an editor to count the number of characters, I wrongly thought that it would be cut at 255 characters for the String Type as such.
This code is what is needed to answer the question:
For the RegEx pattern, see also MS Access VBA cannot deal with lookarounds. Double early/late RegEx match needed. "Run-time error '5017': Application-defined or object-defined error" - Stack Overflow with a Regex pattern that would also work if there was just one column or if the "error" column was the first column, or if the neighboured column does not end with AS .... There, the code just searches for the comma before the AS .... That will not help if you have commas inside the column definition (which I do not have).
Option Compare Database

Function extractErrorColumnAndWhereCondition(obj_SQL As String) As Variant
    Dim error As String
    Dim whereCondition As String
    Dim regex As Object
    Dim matches As Object
    Dim regexPattern As String
    
    regexPattern = "AS (\w+)(?: AS error)?.*\s+INTO (\w+) FROM.*WHERE(.*)"
    
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regex
        .Global = False
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = regexPattern
    End With
    
    Set matches = regex.Execute(obj_SQL)
    
    If matches.Count > 0 Then
        error = matches(0).SubMatches(0)
        whereCondition = matches(0).SubMatches(2)
        extractErrorColumnAndWhereCondition = Array(error, whereCondition)
    Else
        extractErrorColumnAndWhereCondition = Array("", "")
    End If
End Function

Sub DurchsucheAccessfile_Nameen()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim fld As Object
    Dim db As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim array_output As Variant
    Dim obj_SQL As String
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(".\my_folder")
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder("K:\MS Access\my_folder")
    
    Dim targetDB As Object
    Dim object_type As String
    Dim object_kind As String
'    Set targetDB = Application.DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(".\my_file.accdb")
    Set targetDB = Application.DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase("K:\MS Access\my_file.accdb")
    
    For Each file In fld.Files
        file_Name = file.Name
        If Right(file_Name, 4) = ".mdb" Or Right(file_Name, 6) = ".accdb" Then
            Set db = Application.DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(file.Path)
            
            For Each obj In db.TableDefs
                obj_Name = obj.Name
                If Left(obj_Name, 4) <> "MSys" And Left(obj_Name, 1) <> "~" Then
                    Set rs = targetDB.OpenRecordset("my_file")
                    rs.AddNew
                    rs("file_Name").Value = file_Name
                    rs("obj_Name").Value = obj_Name
                    rs("LastUpdated").Value = obj.LastUpdated
                    If InStr(1, obj_Name, "Formular", vbTextCompare) Then
                        object_type = "Formular"
                    ElseIf InStr(1, obj_Name, "TAB", vbTextCompare) Or InStr(1, obj_Name, "dbo_", vbTextCompare) Then
                        object_type = "Table"
                    Else
                        object_type = "Unknown"
                    End If
                    rs("object_type").Value = object_type
                    If object_type = "Table" Then
                        If InStr(1, obj_Name, "_v_", vbTextCompare) Then
                            object_kind = "Linked View"
                        ElseIf InStr(1, obj_Name, "_tbl", vbTextCompare) Then
                            object_kind = "Linked Table"
                        Else
                            object_kind = "loaded"
                        End If
                    ElseIf object_type = "Formular" Then
                        object_kind = "Formular"
                    Else
                        object_kind = "Unknown"
                    End If
                    rs("object_kind").Value = object_kind
                    rs("SourceTableName").Value = obj.SourceTableName
                    rs.Update
                End If
            Next obj
            
            
            For Each obj In db.QueryDefs
                obj_Name = obj.Name
                If Left(obj_Name, 1) <> "~" Then
                    rs.AddNew
                    rs("file_Name").Value = file_Name
                    rs("obj_Name").Value = obj_Name
                    rs("LastUpdated").Value = obj.LastUpdated
                    rs("object_type").Value = "Abfrage"
                    obj_SQL = obj.SQL
                    If InStr(1, obj_SQL, "into ", vbTextCompare) Then
                        object_kind = "select into"
                    Else
                        object_kind = "select"
                    End If
                    rs("object_kind").Value = object_kind
                    rs("Query_SQL").Value = obj_SQL
                    array_output = extractErrorColumnAndWhereCondition(obj_SQL)
                    If IsArray(array_output) Then
                        rs("error").Value = array_output(0)
                        rs("Where_Condition").Value = array_output(1)
                    End If
                    rs.Update
                End If
            Next obj
            
            db.Close
        End If
    Next file
    
    targetDB.Close
End Sub

